# Test if a object is partially included into an array with mocha

Tags: mocha.js, chai

Working with Mocha and Chai, I'm usually using `haveProperties` to test if an object partially contains another object:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(value) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, '_str', {
            value
        });
    }

    toString() {
        return this._str;
    }
}

const bar = new Foo('bar');
const twinBar = new Foo('bar');
const baz = new Foo('baz');

const owner = {
    a: 4,
    b: bar,
    c: 7
};

const partial1 = {
    a: 4,
    b: twinBar
};

const partial2 = {
    a: 4,
    b: baz
};


owner.should.haveProperties(partial1); // success
owner.should.haveProperties(partial2); // failure
```

Notice that `haveProperties` works "deeply" and even for objects that do not have enumerable properties, `bar` and `twinBar` are considered equals although `bar` and `baz` are considered different.

Now, I'm in a situation where I need to know if my partial object is included (with the deep equality constraint provided by `haveProperties`) into an **array** of objects.

```
const ownerArr = [{
    a: 4,
    b: bar,
    c: 7
}, {
    a: 3
}];


ownerArr.should.(????)(partial1); // should succeed
ownerArr.should.(????)(partial2); // should fail
```

And I don't have any idea how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Chai Things](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-things/)

In your case this should work (not tested)

```
ownerArr.should.include.something.that.deep.equals(partial)
```

try this:

```
 ownerArr.should.shallowDeepEqual(partial);
```

You may have to do `npm install chai-shallow-deep-equal` for above to work

make sure that Chai Things plugin is installed

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532981/match-partial-objects-in-chai-assertions). second answer in that link should also work.

Comment: `AssertionError: expected an element of [ Array(2) ] to deeply equal { a: 4, b: { d: 3 } } `

Comment: Thanks! It indeed works perfectly with my example but I realize that in my true project, I have some properties of my objects that have no enumerable properties and so it always assert to true, even if my objects are differents :(

Comment: @Guid  Glad it  works for you , can you mark it as answer. You have to include actual code for someone to be look.

Comment: @Guid , ideally you should mark this as answer , keeping everything same as previously in question and open new question for new doubts.