# Is it possible to compare two objects only between the keys / properties they both share?

Tags: javascript, json, chai

So I have two objects

```
address: {
  id: 1234,
  city: "foo",
  country: "bar",
  name: "baz"
}
```

and

```
defaultAddress: { 
  id: 1234,
  city: "foo",
  country: "bar",
  firstName: "ba",
  lastName: "z"
}
```

If I try to do a straight up comparison / assertion between them, i.e.

```
expect(address).to.contain(defaultAddress)
```

(or the other way around), it'll fail because each contains fields the other does not

> (AssertionError: expect {address} to have a property 'firstName')

I only want to comparing the values in the keys they both share. Is it possible to do something like that programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to match the objects on the subset of shared keys. This can be done as follows.

```
for(const key in address) {
  if(typeof defaultAddress[key] !== 'undefined') {
    expect(address[key]).to.equal(defaultAddress[key])
  }
}
```

Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532981/match-partial-objects-in-chai-assertions).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `.to.include.any.keys` as

```
expect(defaultAddress).to.include.any.keys(...Object.keys(address));
```

Didn't test though

Comment: Oh, I should read the chai documentation, i didn't know you could do that :/

Answer (score 0):

I would underscore an essential aspect which has not been mentioned yet.

While it is always possible to write a function

```js
f(a, b) {...}
```

testing if the two objects `a`, `b` share same values in correspondence of common keys, it should be clearly stated that such a function cannot be considered a definition of equivalence, because every equivalence is required to be transitive.

```js
assert(f({a: 0}, {a: 0, b: 1}))  
assert(f({a: 0, b: 1}, {b: 1}))  
assert(!f({a: 0}, {b: 1}))
```