# How to find specific property in objects without name in array

Tags: cypress, chai

I have an API whose response looks like this (notice that it is objects without name in array):

```js
{
 offers: [
  {
   sticker: null,
  },
  {
   sticker: null,
   score: "67",
  },
  {
   sticker: null,
  },
  {
   sticker: null,
  },
  {
   sticker: null,
   score: "70",
  }
 ]
}
```

How to check if the property score exists in this API response? I tried using

```js
expect(resp.body.offers.some((offer: any) => offer.score !== undefined && typeof offer.score === "string")).to.be.true;
```

and many other ideas I had but nothing works. It will always throw error `expected false to be true`.

Comment: Note that this is also the problem with structuring your assertion in this way - unless you're actually testing something whose whole job is to return a boolean, asserting `.to.be.true` means you get no meaningful feedback from the test when it fails.

Comment: (Something like `expect(resp.body).to.have.property("offers").that.includes(...)` would be better, but [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29532981/3001761) you'd have to extend Chai to get partial object matching.)

Comment: Of course I can do it with `.has.property("score")` but this will throw me error **expected [ Array(21) ] to have property 'score'** but I dunno how to handle that array.

Comment: `.has.property` would work on a single object, not an array of them. When you're looking for something within an array, think `.include[s]` (aliased as `.contain[s]`). Part of the challenge is also how vague the requirement is - having more control over the API response would make it much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion is actually passing (according to the code you posted), so it looks like the `response` *is* the offers array

```js
const response = {
  offers: [
    {
      sticker: null,
    },
    {
      sticker: null,
      score: "67",
    },
    {
      sticker: null,
    },
    {
      sticker: null,
    },
    {
      sticker: null,
      score: "70",
    }
  ]
}

// original assertion passes
expect(response.offers.some(offer => {
  return offer.score !== undefined && typeof offer.score === "string"}
), 'original assertion passes').to.be.true
```

---

Cypress lodash is really useful for parsing object lists, here's a few examples:

```js
const score67 = Cypress._.find(response.offers, {score: "67"})
expect(score67).not.to.be.undefined

const score68 = Cypress._.find(response.offers, {score: "68"})
expect(score68).to.be.undefined

const firstWithScore = Cypress._.find(response.offers, 'score')
expect(firstWithScore.score).to.be.a('string')

const scores = Cypress._.flatMap(response.offers, (offer) => offer.score).filter(Boolean)
expect(scores).to.deep.equal(['67', '70'])
expect(scores.every(s => typeof s === 'string')).to.eq(true)
```

[image]

Comment: Whats weird is, that it passes when I declared it thru const like you, but it not passes and gives undefined when it comes from API. So when it is declared in cypress it will pass, when it comes from API it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by this from Aladin:

```
const scores = Cypress._.flatMap(response.offers, (offer) => offer.score).filter(Boolean)
expect(scores.every(s => typeof s === 'string')).to.eq(true)
```

but whats weird is that all other lodash will fail. Declared response inside test will pass, but when it comes from API response, it will fail.